# Symfony missing bootstrap.php.cache

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services

I am using continuous deployment with jenkins on AWS. Everything is OK, but when I look on my page, there is this error:

```
Warning: require_once(/var/app/web/../app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/app/web/app.php on line 6 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/app/web/../app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/app/web/app.php on line 6
```

I know, it's because I miss bootstrap.php.cache which should be generated by composer, but there is nothing.

In dockerfile I use `RUN composer install --no-scripts --optimize-autoloader`

and in entrypoint I have `composer run-script post-install-cmd --no-interaction`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Execute following command:

```
sudo php vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

Comment: Update: in my current version of sensio/distribution-bundle (5.0) the script has been moved, try `sudo php vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php`

Comment: This will do run all other scripts as well
sudo composer symfony-scripts

Comment: running cache:clear for all the environments solved my problem

Comment: The script has been moved, and the arguments to generate in var are `php vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php 0 0 1` otherwise it generates it in `app/`

Answer (score 8):

A late comment but :

The `boostrap.php.cache` file is generated by a hooks the composer.json scripts section. More specifically :

```
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
```

When running the composer install with the `--no-scripts` those hooks are **not executed**.

However, this file is being generated for performance. As is not as relevant to later versions of PHP. You could simply remove it.

1. Remove the file
2. Edit the index.php or app.php to remove the require bootstrap.php.cache
3. Removing the hook from the composer.json file

Answer (score 2):

Search for `"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",`
 your `composer.json` if it exists there probably you just need to run 'composer install',

or easiest solution is  try to run on sf >= 3

```
php vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

Answer (score 0):

in web folder you have to add the bootstrap.php.cache . It is already being in the app folder of your symfony.

Comment: it is already exist in app folder. you can just copy and paste it from app to web folder.

Comment: I though composer will generate it? Because I have in my composer.json this:
   "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap"