# symfony 2.3 can not create bootstrap.php.cache file, complains over parameter bag

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am tasked with updating a symfony 2.3 app. It went out of style a loong time ago...

The error I get from both app_dev.php and when trying to run the symfony console is:

> Fatal error: Cannot use
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag as
> ParameterBag because the name is already in use in
> /myPath/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 1958

I googled it, and the suggestion is to run **cache:clear** which obviously creates a catch22 situation for me. The other suggestion I found was to do **composer update** or composer install, which doesn't work either due to this little fella:

This thread (https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9402) suggests to use a different version of sensio distribution bundle, for instance 3.0.36 is supposed to work with symfony 2.3.

I also had to downgrade composer to 2.2 in order to install according to these packages (otherwise some eventDispatcher or other was not compatible). After composer has gone it's course, though, I still end up with the initial parameterBag error at the top.

Is there a way of fixing this? Not permanently, the aim is to move through deprecations one by one, but in order to do that I would need to get the app up and running in it's "old self" =)

I also tried these suggestions ([Symfony missing bootstrap.php.cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35081480/symfony-missing-bootstrap-php-cache)). Manually running the script to generate the bootstrap file doesn't help, and removing the bootstrap file and commenting it out in app.php and app_dev.php certainly doesn't help, then it just goes on to complain about

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel" not found in...
```

So I assume that comment was aimed at a much later version of symfony.

I know that all my dependencies are extremely old, the pan is to get it up and running, and start updating/migrating one step at a time.

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "3.0.36",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.0-alpha1",
        "avalanche123/imagine-bundle": "v2.1"
    
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Having googled "ParameterBag as ParameterBag because the name is already in use in", the only other hit I get is this from 2022: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions/46848

Given that this doesn't seem to have been reported back in the days when Symfony 2 was supported, I wonder if the incompatibilty is with something that's been released long after mainstream use of Symfony 2 had ended.

Could you set the versions of everything? e.g. php 5 + set all composer dependencies to the latest patches available on a specific date when Symfony 2.3 was widely used, e.g. 2015-06-30

Comment: Been a long time but as I recall the bootstrap file is not actually needed.  Try editing app/console and comment out the require statement and see what happens.  Might just get a different error but maybe not.  And yes you will need quite a bit of old stuff.  Maybe you could track down a docker configuration?